# How do I conditionally enqueue script for CPT single post type with plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags

I'm writing a plugin that defines its own CPT "properties" and I want to enqueue a script specifically in single posts.

It runs without my attempt at a conditional statement just fine but I don't need it to load on every page so I'd like to make this conditional.

This code is in my plugin root just after my includes.

```
if ( 'properties' == get_post_type() ) {
    if (wp_script_is('owl.carousel.js', 'enqueued')) {
        return;
    } else {
        wp_register_script('owl.carousel.min.js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/owl.carousel.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('owl.carousel.min.js');
    }
}
```

I've also tried `is_sigular('properties')` but that didn't work either.

I must be missing something silly...

Comment: I think you have mistyping. Try to use `in_singular('properties')` instead of `is_sigular` More info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular#Custom_Post_Types)

Comment: Looks like I miskeyed in this question.  I did use `is_singular('properties')` .  I'm wondering if it's an issue of location now, I've added the same conditional in one of my template files and it ran.

Comment: Is this running inside of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook?

Comment: So the problem was solved? Or not?

Comment: Well, is singular ran and returned true in the template file.  I don't want to enqueue the script through the theme though.

Comment: You should add the enqueue to the plugin that adds the CPT (which should be a plugin if it's already not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your code runs in [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook.

Also checkout your script handle `'owl.carousel.js'`. In `wp_script_is()`, it is not the same than in the 2 later functions in which you enter it as `'owl.carousel.min.js'`.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_properties_scripts' );

function enqueue_properties_scripts() {
    if ( 'properties' === get_post_type() ) {
        if ( wp_script_is( 'owl.carousel.min.js', 'enqueued' ) ) {
            return;

        } else {
            wp_register_script( 'owl.carousel.min.js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'owl.carousel.min.js' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is it...  Looks like I forgot this step.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisStage glad it helped you out, check my last edit about your script handle...

Comment: Minor improvement: If you already `return` in the `if`–clause, you can leave off the `else`. Hint: An `else` is in 99% of all cases obsolete.

Comment: Hi @kaiser, feel free to edit the answer as you judge it good.

Comment: It was less about this specific answer as a more general note. It does not hurt the process that is offered.

Comment: why would it be necessary to add the step of checking `wp_script_is`? WordPress will already take care of this. Also `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` make no sense if used like in the example: if you are going to use it right away anyway you can simply omit `wp_register_script` and use `wp_enqueue_script` right away. See also https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#usage. Perhaps I miss something?